# Firestore does not return result in this set operation

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-firestore, set

Reading the [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data) but still can't get this to work.

In the code the `docRef` is undefined even the set operation is successful.

Why is that, I was expecting the `docRef` to be the value I just set.

```
/**
 * Create new Tag
 * @param {name} name
 * @param {category} category
 */
export function saveNewTag(name, category) {
    return (dispatch, getState, firebase) => {
        dispatch(addNewTagStart());
        firebase.db
            .collection(FIRESTORE.GLOBAL_TAGS)
            .doc(name)
            .set({ [FIRESTORE.TAG_NAME]: name, [FIRESTORE.CATEGORY]: category }, { merge: true })
            .then(docRef => {
                // docRef is undefined here
                dispatch(addNewTagSuccess(docRef));
            })
            .catch(error => {
                dispatch(addNewTagFailure(error));
            });
    };
}
```

Image showing the undefined `docRef`

[image]

Comment: I don't believe you can promise chain after the set, as you'd *then* be doing a get.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Firestore's `set()` operation returns a `Promise<void>`, so you can't get the `DocumentReference` from there.

Instead, you can put the `DocumentReference` in a variable and re-use it from there. Something like:

```
let docRef = firebase.db
    .collection(FIRESTORE.GLOBAL_TAGS)
    .doc(name);

docRef.set({ [FIRESTORE.TAG_NAME]: name, [FIRESTORE.CATEGORY]: category }, { merge: true })
    .then(() => {
        dispatch(addNewTagSuccess(docRef));
    })
    .catch(error => {
        dispatch(addNewTagFailure(error));
    });
```

Comment: Yes this work, the [docs](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#add_a_document) is missing the explicits creating of the `docRef` variable, so I thought the `docRef` was promise chained..

Comment: I find it most helpful to keep the reference documentation handy in cases like this, which is how I knew that `set` returns ` Promise<void>`: https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/js/firebase.firestore.DocumentReference#set